# Starting an new activity in unique memory?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A and an activity B. A is the root activity, which starts activity B.

Both activities instantiate a singleton class C. I would like them to have their own unique class C, but activity B always ends up with the C from activity A.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.scrollMotion.bundleRunner.A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bundle" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.scrollMotion.B"
        android:label="ShelfBundleActivity"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:taskAffinity="com.scrollMotion.ShelfBundleActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I start activity B from A in the following way:

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, B.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I am trying to keep the two activities in separate memory and stacks.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jerry

Comment: So, now you wish you didn't have a singleton, am I right?

Comment: So you are saying you want two instances of a `singleton` i.e. you want a `doubleton` i.e you don't want a singleton? Why don't you make C a simple class? Each new instance will be unique (except any members you explicitly make common between the instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Singlton isn't the best programming practice, but sometimes when you are working with legacy code, you have no choice.

Anyway, I did not expect my static singleton class to be accessible outside of an android task. Yet it is.

In my app, new apps ( of the same type ) can be spawned onto the application stack several levels deep. I needed a clean singleton for each app. When an app gets popped of the application stack, the singleton would be corrupted with data from the last app.

What I ended up doing was creating a hash map of static HashMap

Thanks for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make class C a singleton. This is literally what a singleton means, they're terrible things, and this is exactly why they should not be employed by anybody, ever.

Comment: In Android, singletons are a bit of a necessary evil, though they are ideally hidden behind some well-implemented API written by experienced developers and available via a library (see: event buses, image caches, etc.). That being said, in this case, this would appear to be a clear case where a regular data member, not a singleton, is the right answer.

Comment: If you're going to make sweeping statements such as "they're terrible things" and "they should not be employed...", it would help strengthen your argument if you provide evidence to back them up. If you don't, then at a cursory glance, those statements may seem to merely reflect what may be purely personal opinion. The only valid point of your answer is in the first sentence recommending the OP doesn't use a singleton but as the OP clearly doesn't understand the 'single' in 'singleton', without further explanation on your part, your answer would be more suited as a comment on the question.

Comment: Using a singleton isn't the best idea, but sometimes it is the best option. All I am looking for is a way to start a new activity in a new context, with a separate heap and stack.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert at all, but there is also a pattern called [multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). You can change that singleton class to multiton, and for selecting the right instance you are looking for, pass activity reference (or anything shared across all activity) to instance function. Also if there is something like that globally available, you can check that in instance function and return respective instance without changing the API.